# Regular partition in the Riemann sum Openstax Calculus 2

Tags: calculus

I am currently studying some mathematics using [openstax](https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-2/pages/1-2-the-definite-integral). I am having a difficult time understanding what the following means:

> It is also worth noting here that we have retained the use of a
> regular partition in the Riemann sums. This restriction is not
> strictly necessary. Any partition can be used to form a Riemann sum.
> However, if a nonregular partition is used to define the definite
> integral, it is not sufficient to take the limit as the number of
> subintervals goes to infinity. Instead, we must take the limit as the
> width of the largest subinterval goes to zero.

I am guessing that *the use of a regular partition* means either (1) we have "blocks" of area or (2) we have a closed interval [a, b] that we are calculating on.

I am unsure what parition mean, I am again guessing that it is the closed interval [a, b].

My confusion is constant through the quote but I cannot extract even a single quess about what *the largest subinterval goes to zero* means. Can anybody explain in a different way what the text is trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

A partition of the interval $[a, b]$ is a set of points: $$\{ x_0 = a, x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n = b \}$$
Each pair of points defines a subinterval. 
If the partition is regular, then the width of each subinterval is the same, so $\Delta x = \displaystyle\frac{b - a}{n}$. In this case, as the number of subintervals approaches infinity, the width of each subinterval approaches zero, and the sum approaches the value of the definite integral it represents. 
If the partition is not regular, then the width of each subinterval does not have to be the same. In this case, we must force the width of the largest subinterval to approach zero in order for the Riemann sum to converge to the value of the definite integral it represents.

Comment: Do we repeat this process of "force the width of the largest subinterval to approach zero"? It seems as if you are saying that if we, for example, cut up a graph in 5 pieces where 4 pieces are the same size but the 5th is a bit bigger then we can reduce the biggest piece to a point (y-value) to get the area of the graph. However we still have 4 pieces untouched, meaning we cannot have applied any calculation or change on the whole graph, ergo I get confused because that is a really weird thing to say.